# yarn npm global modules

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

In the past I used npm to install some modules globally.
Now that I've started a new project I want to begin using yarn.

I'm confused what will happen if I install a new module globally using yarn.
Will yarn convert the global node_modules directory ?
Or do you I have to delete the global directory and reinstall each module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find where the global bins will be with `yarn global ls`

From the docs, you can also specify where the bins will be:

> yarn global bin will output the location where Yarn will install symlinks to your installed executables. You can configure the base location with yarn config set prefix . For example, yarn config set prefix ~/.yarn will ensure all global packages will have their executables installed to ~/.yarn/bin.

The default location is in ~/.config/yarn/global

[Yarn Global Doc](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global)

Comment: So will node use yarn's or npm's global directory when resolving the module ?

Comment: By default it will use Yarns, but you can configure it to use npm's.

Comment: I'm guessing yarn does this by prepending it's path to some environment variable that node uses to resolve modules ?

Comment: It's done by installing symlinks, detailed here: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global - if you want to point it to the node  bins you'd use this: `yarn config set prefix <filepath>`

Comment: No.  Node doesn't know about yarn or npm.  But yarn and npm know about node.  So, something must be updated in node's run time configuration by npm and yarn.  When node evaluates the require function, it applies its resolution policy, which is implemented in its module subsystem, and it ends up scanning a list of paths, which are configurable.  So, I believe that if module X were installed globally by npm and yarn, and npm's global path appears first and wins.

Answer (score 6):

**NPM**

- *bin* is linked into `$(npm prefix -g)/bin`
- *module* is installed into `$(npm prefix -g)/lib/node_modules`

**YARN**

- *bin* is linked into `yarn global bin`
- *module* is installed into `yarn global dir`

You can **config** yarn to use the  configuration of npm:

- config **bin** , `yarn config set prefix $(npm prefix -g)`
- config **module**, I don't recommend you config yarn to use the path which npm uses, it will delete npm even,after you intall a package globally.

  if you dare,try below

  > yarn global add react --global-folder $(npm prefix -g)/lib

Comment: I was trying yarn, default location for executable of global module will be at "\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\.bin"

I was confused with ..\\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin